# ASP.NET Core using IOptionsMonitor<T> throwing exception in a different thread

Tags: asp.net-core

In my web application, I have a custom configuration file which I want to monitor for changes and update the application settings immediately. So I am using `IOptionsMonitor<T>` to get this done. It works well.

As per the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.extensions.options.ioptionsmonitor-1?view=dotnet-plat-ext-6.0) the method that gets called when configuration file changed is wired up like below.

```
var data = _serviceProvider.GetRequiredService<IOptionsMonitor<MySettings>>();
data.OnChange(OnReaderSettingOptionsChanged);
```

Within the `OnReaderSettingOptionsChanged()` method, I do some validations and there is a need to throw an exception on an edge case so that application shouldn't continue.

The problem is when I throw the exception, I expect to see a error on browser (dev mode with details or normal error otherwise). But it's not showing because according to [this](https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/issues/44381) exception gets fired in another thread.

So, is there another way for me to get this across to browser?

Comment: I don't have a solution, but an approach. Seems you need to marshal the error back to the web thread somehow. If you can't do this directly, you need so set some piece of data that can be checked on the web thread.

Comment: I don't think my ideas are good idea on this case, but per my understanding, 2 apporaches, one is in your website, assuming you have a _layout.cshtml then you can add a monitor methon to monitor if there's a change in your backend, e.g. when throwing the exception, you can edit a flag in your database then the monitor will continuously watch this flag. Another one is creating a notification model, then when throwing exception, pushing a notification to the client(browser)..